# Can a non-committee-member ask questions while watching a friend's PhD defense?

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

I'm going to a PhD defense tomorrow and his topic and methods are sort of close to what I have in mind for pursuing myself, and I'd like to be an active participant during the talk; what is the typical etiquette to follow?  Do only the committee members ask questions during the defense?

Comment: Impossible to answer since every institute/country has its own rules regarding PhD defences.

Comment: Further, at least at the institutions (USA, Netherlands) I have been at, the PhD defense is largely _ceremonial_ in nature. Since they are a friend, you have plenty of time afterwards to (a) buy them a beverage of their choice, and (b) ask detailed questions.

Comment: *Before* the talk starts, simply ask the chair of the PhD defense committee whether a question during or after the talk from your side would be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on your country, university, and department. In some places, questions by non-faculty are rare. In other places, the discussion can get out of hand.

As it sounds like you are only starting your research and that this is your first PhD defense, you may want to consider sitting quietly and watching and learning what happens. After the defense, you can contact the student, and any committee members, and strike up a conversation.

Comment: Exactly. In some schools, there are no questions during the public presentation; at others, the discussion can go for an unlimited period of time! (If I remember correctly, my public phase went on for two hours, and the private phase lasted about fifteen minutes!)

Comment: On the other hand, it may also be that saving questions for later is slightly harmful to the defendant as, e.g., a defence that did not inspire any questions from the audience is considered bad or catering the wrong audience. Here, the audience cannot do anything wrong with asking questions and it is the job of the chair to keep the discussion sane. — *After the defense, you can contact […] any committee members, and strike up a conversation.* – Here it is quite common for everybody but the advisor to leave immediately after the actual defence is over.